# Авто изменение размера ListView в WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте!
Как сделать в WPF у ListView авто изменение размера (самого контрола) по содержимому, тесть что бы не появлялась полоса прокрутки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Элементы могут добавляться и удаляться, так что нужно что бы ListView всегда подстраивал свой размер под свои элементы.

Или может кто то знает как правильней реализовать эту функцию выбора студии.

Comment: не совсем понятно о чем идет речь, если места недостаточно, то появление скролла - логичное поведение

Comment: @FoggyFinder я не хочу что бы он появлялся, я хочу что бы ListView сам свой размер увеличивал

Comment: не задавай ему(или его предшественникам) жёстко значение ширины и высоты и он будет сам увеличиваться